# Bootstrap 4 modal not showing again after having been hidden

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I have a function to hide my modal:

```
function hideModal(){ 

    $('#mainModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $("#mainModal").modal("hide");
    });
}
```

When I open a modal for the first time, it works fine. I then call hideModal() to hide it, which also works.

I find that any subsequent call to open the modal:

```
$('#mainModal').modal();
```

...results in the modal being opened before very quickly disappearing again.

I'm not running any code after opening the second modal.

I've checked my code to make sure that there is only one instance of bootstrap is being loaded.

Why would calling $('#mainModal').modal(); work the first time, but not subsequent times?

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Can you post *all* of the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Both hiding and showing the modal are async events, which means there going to take a few ms to complete.

*So*, if you call `modal()` or `modal('show')` while it's still hiding, it won't show. Inversely, if you call `modal('hide')` while it's not yet shown, it won't hide.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys. I need to keep that listener ie not just have:

```
$("#mainModal").modal("hide");
```

otherwise the modal doesn't hide, due to the ("show") call still being in action when ("hide") was called.

jQuery have an .off listener, which removes the listener after it fires just once.

So I replaced:

```
$('#mainModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $("#mainModal").modal("hide");
});
```

with:

```
$('#mainModal').one('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $("#mainModal").modal("hide");
});
```

and am now getting the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

What happens is that the first (and subsequent!) time you hide the modal by calling the `hideModal` function, you set an event handler that closes the modal each time you show it. This should work, it just hides the modal when called:

```
function hideModal() { 
    $("#mainModal").modal("hide");
}
```

Comment: I understand what you both mean, and the UI delay is the reason I added $('#mainModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(e) {
        $("#mainModal").modal("hide");
    }); as $("#mainModal").modal("hide"); on it's own wasn't working ie the show() was still in action when hide() was called. However, it seems adding that listener is what's making subsequent show() calls fail. I just releaised that jquery also have a one() listener call, which kills the listener after it fires once, so I've replaced the .on with .one and am getting the desired result. I'll update my question. Thank you guys.